# Bizarre Windows Update issues - loss of connectivity

Tags: dell, update, wsus

I'm seeing a truly bizarre issue that I'm having trouble isolating.

Scenario : A stack of Dell Poweredge servers acting in a stable cluster. Attempted to apply some windows updates, servers lost internet and domain trust. Could not re-establish domain trust. Uninstalled update, it worked. Reinstalled, everything okay. Same thing on another server so I took the decision to rebuild the baseline. Servers have been rebuilt from the ground up:
Latest firmware has been applied (BIOS, NICs, RAID etc) and latest level of drivers. 
Standard 2012R2 Datacenter build, networked and then into the updates. 
At different stages of the build, updates are being applied which knock out internet connection.  DNS fully resolves, you can ping, traceroute etc but the browser doesn't work. Additionally if you try to join the domain at this point it's "Network path not found". Multiple attempts to restore connectivity fail.

In some cases a server gets to the stage where it's ready to join to the domain, after which another set of updates then appear post-domain join, some of which will then knock out the internet connection again. At this point the trust relationship with the domain is lost too.

Most of the time, a simple process of uninstalling the most recent update and reboot will restore connection. You can then re-install the exact same update and the server continues to behave itself. If it's on the domain at this point, I have to reset the machine account to restore trust. 
Then, it will happen again at a later stage of the build with a different update.

I have ruled out it being a single update responsible as it happens at various stages with different rollups being applied.
Have tried multiple driver/firmware revisions for the server. There is no firewall block on the network. No security software. No Windows firewall.
I even sysprepped a server right back and rebuilt it's teamed NIC infrastructure and the internet still failed until I rolled back the update at which point it works. Then rolled it forward again and the problem is gone.

Most of the time I can reach a point where the server is stable and in production use, as long as I don't apply any more updates.

Does anyone have any experience of anything remotely similar to this?

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd post an update on this,  now solved problem.

As it transpires, Windows Updates were a complete red herring. It just so happened that it was updates I was running whilst the problem occurred, but in fact it seems it was simply the process of rebooting that killed the TCPIP stack. 
I was able to recreate the problem several times over by a simple reboot, and then resetting by Netsh Winsock Reset and reboot would bring it back to life. 
Bizarrely, often uninstalling a recent update and rebooting would have the same effect - but not always. 
What was behind it?  It seems to be the NIC cards. Although the latest firmware and drivers,  one of the settings for RSS (Receive Side Scaling) was causing the problem.  This allows NIC traffic to be distributed over multiple processors rather than restricted to just one. A typical performance tuning tweak that causes more problems than it solves.  I disabled it and hey-presto, everything is stable again. I can patch and reboot to my heart's content without losing the TCPIP stack :)

A very obscure problem but perhaps someone else will find something similar and disabling RSS may help.